# Is it possible to Insert a string array into jtable using for loop

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I am facing a trouble, that I  can't insert a string array into a jTable. The scene is that I have some selected values in an array, and I want to insert that value into jTable.

My code is here:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class as extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public as() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    t1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    t2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    t1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"122", "a", null, null},
            {"123", "b", null, null},
            {"124", "c", null, null},
            {"125", "d", null, null},
            {"126", "e", null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(t1);

    t2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2"
        }
    ));


private void jButton1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

            Vector R_D=new Vector();

    if(t1.getRowCount()>0){
        String[] ary = new String[t1.getRowCount()];
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<t1.getRowCount();i++){                
                R_D.add(t1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
                ary[i]=t1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary)+i);
                ((DefaultTableModel) t2.getModel()).addRow(ary);  

            }
        }
        catch(Exception d)
            {System.out.println(d.getMessage());}


    }
}                                      

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {        

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new as().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTable t1;
private javax.swing.JTable t2;
// End of variables declaration
```

I have the right answer in that Array named  `ary[]`.

I need is to copy all array values into separate jTable Rows.

But the result ends in some empty table without showing any errors

just see the cropped screen shots

[image: Input]

This is the table having selected employees list.

After clicking Create Attendance List button, the result is

[image: Actualand wrong answer]

The table will look like this.

But I need a result which something look like this

[image: Want this result]

Please help me.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with upper case characters. When you create your `SSCCE` fix your variable names.

Comment: Sorry,my mistake,,I edited it,Take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that I can't insert a string array into a jTable.

Well I don't see any code where you attempt to do that.

Start by reading the `DefaultTableModel` API. You can easily create a DefaultTableModel with your data. You can:

1. create an empty DefaultTableModel and then use the `addRow(...)` method to add a row in your loop.
2. You can create a DefaultTableModel with the number of rows that your want. Then you can use the `setValueAt(...)` method to change the data in each row.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Edit:

An example of a `SSCCE` that simply adds a row of data to a table when a button is pressed. The code creates an Array with two values and then invokes the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableRowColumn2 extends JFrame
{
    private final static String LETTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    JTable table;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JButton button;

    public TableRowColumn2()
    {
        //  Create table

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {new Integer(1), "A"},
            {new Integer(2), "B"},
            {new Integer(3), "C"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Number","Letter"};
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model)
        {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
            {
                return true;
            }
        };

        table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( table.getDefaultRenderer(Integer.class) );

        //  Add table and a Button panel to the frame

        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );

        button = new JButton( "Add Row" );
        button.setMnemonic('A');
        buttonPanel.add( button );
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                model.addRow( createRow() );
                int row = table.getRowCount() - 1;
                table.changeSelection(row, 0, false, false);
                table.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

    }

    private Object[] createRow()
    {
        Object[] newRow = new Object[2];
        int row = table.getRowCount();
        newRow[0] = Integer.toString(row + 1);
        row = (row % 26) + 1;
        newRow[1] = LETTERS.substring(row-1, row);
        return newRow;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableRowColumn2 frame = new TableRowColumn2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In your case you will need to get each selected row. Then for each row you will:

1. Create an Array for the data you want to copy.
2. Then you invoke the addRow(...) method on the second TableModel

So basically you need to change the code in the ActionListner to add a loop to do the above two steps.

Comment: ,I already tried that piece of code using vector ,But no use.Here is it    `((DefaultTableModel) Tbl_Exp_Mgr.getModel()).insertRow(0, R_D);`    So I removed that part.

Comment: Is there any Idea,Please tell me.Its very urgent.My brain is dead.

Comment: My table is empty.So I cant use `setValueAt(...) ' method.But no use

Comment: I already suggested the addRow(...) method. Also, If you only have a single column why are you using a JTable. A JList would be easier. In any case you haven't posted a `SSCCE` so I can't help. The point of a SSCCE is to simplify the problem. So create a frame with a JTable and a copy button to create your second JTable/JList. The complete code should be about 20-30 lines of code.

Comment: Sorry Sir, My jTable had 5 columns in total with 0 rows at initial stage.After pressing a copy button the table add rows dynamically.Then getting the 1st value(ie ID),So that I could access remaining details from database based on that ID.And fill the remaining fields in that jTable.[ didn't explain here ].And Thanks for your SSCCE knowledge.Its very helpful for a fresher like me.Thankyou very much for your help

Comment: I don't understand you explanation of the problem. You still haven't posted a `SSCCE` so I still can't help.

Comment: Just edited my question with screen shots.Now you can understand what my problem is

Comment: A picture doesn't help. The point of taking the time to create a `SSCCE` is to understand the concept. The real data and real application is irrelevant to the concept. I already explained how to create a `SSCCE`. I added my own simple `SSCCE` that you can use as a starting point to test your concept. You will need to add a 2nd table to the frame and implement the ActionListener. If you have problems, then post your updated version of the SSCCE!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this methode to add the String[] to the JTable:

First you have to get the model and then you have to add the String[]:

```
((TableModel) Tbl_To.getModel()).addRow(Ary);
```

With this method, your selected data is in one row in the JTable.

Comment: `((DefaultTableModel) JTable.getModel()).addRow(Ary); ` .I tried this code.But the values spreads into entire columns.I need all the values in separate ROWS..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a trick to achieve my target..
I create a dummy array ,then i call the array values just before inserting the row data.After that I use `setValues` to set values of mystring array.Thats what I mean.

here is the code that i edited

```
    Vector R_D=new Vector();

    if(Tbl_AddAttTo.getRowCount()>0){
        String[] Dary = {"nil","nil","nil","nil"};
        String[] ary = new String[Tbl_AddAttTo.getRowCount()];
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<Tbl_AddAttTo.getRowCount();i++){                
                R_D.add(Tbl_AddAttTo.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
                ary[i]=Tbl_AddAttTo.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();

               ((DefaultTableModel) Tbl_Exp_Mgr1.getModel()).addRow(Dary);
                Tbl_Exp_Mgr1.setValueAt(ary[i], i, 0);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception d)
            {System.out.println(d.getMessage());}
    }
```