# How to call the JTable function again

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a GUI interface using java swing that is able to add users to a text file that I treat as a database. The GUI interface has a JTable which pulls the existing items in the text file and displays it initially. Once I go to add a new item, it gets updated on the text file but not on the JTable. This is mainly because I only call the JTable once the way I set up my code. I'm wondering how I can call the JTable multiple times or make a button for it to call a refresh of the table and display the newly added items alongside the old items.

I want it to be able to either call the refresh of the table in the `updateList` function or once the `viewButton` is pressed which triggers an else if statement which can do that in the `actionPerformed` function.

Here is my code:

```
class UserManager extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  private JTextField firstNameField, lastNameField, salaryField;
  private JButton addButton, removeButton, viewButton, sortButton, getButton;
  private JList<Employee> userList;
  private ArrayList<Employee> users;

  public UserManager() {
    setTitle("Employee Manager");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    firstNameField = new JTextField(20);
    lastNameField = new JTextField(20);
    salaryField = new JTextField(20);
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(this);
    removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    removeButton.addActionListener(this);
    viewButton = new JButton("Refresh List"); // POTENTIAL BUTTON TO REFRESH JTABLE?
    viewButton.addActionListener(this);
    sortButton = new JButton("Sort List");
    sortButton.addActionListener(this);

    // Pulling data from text file database
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> databaseData = ReadFile();

    users = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    // Adding existing databaseData to users
    for (int i = 0; i < databaseData.size(); i++) {
      Employee user = new Employee(databaseData.get(i).get(0), databaseData.get(i).get(1), Integer.valueOf(databaseData.get(i).get(2)));
      users.add(user);
    }
    
    userList = new JList<Employee>(users.toArray(new Employee[0]));
    userList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


    JPanel firstNamePanel = new JPanel();
    firstNamePanel.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
    firstNamePanel.add(firstNameField);

    JPanel lastNamePanel = new JPanel();
    lastNamePanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
    lastNamePanel.add(lastNameField);

    JPanel salaryPanel = new JPanel();
    salaryPanel.add(new JLabel("Salary:"));
    salaryPanel.add(salaryField);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(addButton);
    buttonPanel.add(removeButton);
    buttonPanel.add(viewButton);
    buttonPanel.add(sortButton);

    
    // Converting 2D arraylist to normal 2D array for JTable
    String[][] data = databaseData.stream().map(u -> u.toArray(new String[0])).toArray(String[][]::new);

    // Initializing column names of JTable
    String[] columnNames = { "FName", "LName", "Salary" };
    
    // Initializing the JTable (THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO REFRESH)
    JTable j = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    j.setBounds(1000, 1000, 900, 900);

    // adding it to JScrollPane
    JScrollPane table = new JScrollPane(j);
    
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 3));
    mainPanel.add(firstNamePanel);
    mainPanel.add(lastNamePanel);
    mainPanel.add(salaryPanel);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
    mainPanel.add(table);

    
    add(mainPanel);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // "Add" button is clicked
    if (e.getSource() == addButton) {
      String firstName = firstNameField.getText();
      String lastName = lastNameField.getText();
      int salary = 0;
      
      try {
          salary = Integer.parseInt(salaryField.getText());
      } 
      catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a valid salary", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
      }

      // Error check to see if full name and age is entered
      if (!firstName.equals("") && !lastName.equals("")) {
        Employee user = new Employee(firstName, lastName, salary);
        users.add(user);
        updateList();
        firstNameField.setText("");
        lastNameField.setText("");
        salaryField.setText("");

      }
      else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a valid full name", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      }

    } 


    // POTENTIAL BUTTON THAT REFRESHES JTABLE? 
    else if (e.getSource() == viewButton) {
      
    }
  }

  // Updates the list after a CRUD operation is called
  private void updateList() {
    userList.setListData(users.toArray(new Employee[0]));

    try {
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("db.txt", false);
      // BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      // PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

      // Loop through each student and write to the text file
      for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        fw.write(toString(users.get(i).getFirstName(), users.get(i).getLastName(), users.get(i).getSalary()));
      }
      fw.close();

      // CALL A REFRESH FOR THE TABLE HERE??
    }
    catch (IOException io) {

    }

  }


  
  
  // Combing multiple string and ints into a string
  public String toString(String firstName, String lastName, int salary) {
      return firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + salary + "\n";
  }



  // Reading database
  public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ReadFile() {
    try {
      // Choose grades.txt file to look at
      File myObj = new File("db.txt");

      // Create scanner object
      Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);

      // Create 2d list array to hold all the single list arrays of single information
      ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> combinedArr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    
      // While the file reader is still reading lines in the text
      while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        // Read strings of text in txt file
        String data = myReader.nextLine();

        // Get first and last name from a string
        ArrayList<String> temp = GetName(data); 

        // Add the person and their salary to the combined array that holds everyones
        combinedArr.add(temp);
      }

      // Close file once there are no more lines to read
      myReader.close();

      return combinedArr;
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return invalid list string with nothing if error
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Invalid = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    return Invalid;
  }



  // Parses name in db
  public static ArrayList<String> GetName(String data) {
    String first = "";
    String last = "";
    String sal = "";
    // System.out.println(data[0])
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
      if (data.charAt(i) == ',') {
        // Start from 2 indexes after the first occurance of the comma
        for (int j = i+2; j < data.length(); j++) {
          if (data.charAt(j) == ',') {
            for (int n = j+2; n < data.length(); n++) {
              sal += data.charAt(n);
            }
            break;
          }
          last += data.charAt(j);
        }
        break;
      }
      first += data.charAt(i);
    }

    // Initializing package array to send all values
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add(first);
    arr.add(last);
    arr.add(sal);
    
    return arr;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      UserManager frame = new UserManager();
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class Employee {
  // Initalizing variables
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private int salary;

  // Assigning variables
  public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int salary) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.salary = salary;
  }

  // return first name
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  // return last name
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  // return salary
  public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }
}
```

Comment: *display the newly added items alongside the old items.* - just update the DefaultTableModel at the same time you write the data to the file when you add a new item. Recreating the entire TableModel would be lots of extra work, especially if you use custom renderers and editors.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the DefaultTableModel, do I have to initialize that somewhere, or if I reference it will it automatically update the JTable? How would I update it too, is there a function for that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Initializing the JTable (THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO REFRESH)

You don't refresh the table. The data for all Swing components is contained in a "model". You change the data in the model. When changes to the model are made the table is repainted to reflect the change.

So you could either:

1. create a new `DefaultTableModel` (which is unnecessary)
2. update the existing `DefaultTableModel`, by using the `addRow(...)` method to update the model every time you write a new item to your file.

Instead of using code like:

```
JTable j = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

You can use:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
table = new JTable(model)
```

Now you can access the DefaultTableModel any time you need to by creating an instance variable in your class or by using the `table.getModel()` method.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to how I can go about making changes to the table (Sorry for the questions, I'm trying to find examples online but am unable to understand them). So first of all, how can I access this table model from a function that's outside of the scope of where `model` was defined? Every time I try referencing `model` or `table`, I get the `unresolved` error. Secondly, for the `.addRow()`, do I pass in an array since JTables work with arrays or a string?

Comment: You table and/or model need to be defined as "instance" variables in your class, like you do with the JList, not as "local" varaibles. Then any method in your class will be able to reference the table. This is Java 101 and has nothing to special to do with a table or its model. The addRow(...) take either an Array or a Vector which would represent the data in the row. So in your create you create either an Array or Vector and then add the firstName, lastName and salary values.

Comment: Here is a simple example that show how to use the addRow(...) method to add rows of data to the model when a button is clicked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35960360/131872. And another example showing how to read data from a file into a model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64248188/131872

Answer (score 0):

Usually lists and tables are updated through their models. They represent the information shown to the user. You can try this.

Create in your class a new field. Use this field when initializing the table in your constructor.

```
private JTable userTable;
```

In your update function, try this:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
users = // fetch here for your users
for (int i = 0, i < user.length, i++)
    model.addRow(users[i]);
}
// finally set new model in your table
userTable.setModel(model);
userTable.doLayout();
```

Comment: How would I integrate this into my code? Where do I initialize that model and where should I put it? Do I set the JTable equal to that model and once I update that model, it will refresh it automatically?

Comment: Ok, I was reading your code and based by answer on your JList, not on your JTable. But don't worry, it's essentially the same. I'm updating my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: *it's essentially the same.* - the DefaultTableModel does NOT have an addAll(...) method.

Comment: It has an addRow() method.

Comment: Which is not essentially the same as the current suggestion.

Comment: Then how would you take in account for external changes? For a simple example, your answer might work, but if something else changes the file, you answer will fail to show the actual data.

Comment: (1-) Well, if you never make a change to the file and some other external application changes the file you will not be aware of the change either. That is a different question about synchronizing changes from multiple sources. The point of my comment is that your answer uses a method of the ListModel which is NOT available in the DefaultTableModel and therefore should be deleted or changed to be applicable to a JTable. Saying it is essentially the same is NOT an answer and the actual answer should NOT be contained in a comment.

Comment: Well sorry, didn't wanted to confuse anybody. Just was saying that you refer to the model when updating a JList or a JTable.

Comment: @Soccerball123 I updated my answer to fit better your situation.